# body html of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi my code returns all the html of the iframe. I would like just the body html. Any one know how to amend to suit?

Code:

```
alert( $("#uploaderIframe").contents()[0].documentElement.innerHTML );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var iframeHtml = $("#uploaderIframe").contents()[0].documentElement.innerHTML;
var bodyHtml = $(iframeHtml).find("body").html();
alert( bodyHtml );
```

.. probably creates a new DOM node from the innerHTML of the iFrame - I actually suspect that `$(iframeHtml).find("body")` is an empty jQuery object.

Try

```
var bodyHtml = $('#uploaderIframe').contents().find("body").html()
```

Ref: [Traversing/contents](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/contents)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
iframeHtml = $("#uploaderIframe").contents()[0].documentElement.innerHTML;
bodyHtml = $(iframeHtml).find("body");
```